# Boost.Python: Registering Non-Boost.Python Converters

Tags: c++, python, boost-python, sfml

I have a project that uses Boost.Python and SFML. Many of my objects expose SFML types and, in the interest of not reproducing the wheel, I would like to return objects from my own bindings that are wrapped by SFML's Python bindings. For example, I have this class:

```
class MyThing
{
public:
    sf::Image& image() { return _image; }

private:
    sf::Image _image;
};
```

Bindings look like this:

```
class_<MyThing>("MyThing")
    .add_property("image", make_function(&MyThing::image, return_internal_reference<1>()))
    ;
```

Of course, actually trying to access the `mything.image` from Python yields `TypeError: No Python class registered for C++ class sf::Image`, since Boost.Python's conversion registry doesn't know about `sf::Image` (SFML's Python bindings are done with Cython).

Is there any way to tell the Boost.Python conversion registry to wrap `sf::Image` types with ones from SFML's Python bindings?

Comment: I'm not familiar with SFML but you could try and write a to_python converter for the sf::image type, and in that use SFML to create a python sf::image instance.

Comment: @MichaelKoval: No. My "solution" was to use Cython, which was pretty inconvenient.